# Sleep mode in android

Tags: android

I want to know what it means to be in sleep mode for android phone...particularly in refrence to ELAPSED_REALTIME and ELAPSED_REALTIME_Wakeup .In the first case without awaking the cpu  some intents are being fired.

I want to know what it means to be in sleep mode or not awaken in android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sleep mode is a state that the CPU has almost no work to do so he is reducing his frequency to save power.

The wakeup option will wake up the CPU to process the tasks you need.

More info you can read [here](http://skillgun.com/question/304/android/advanced-android/what-is-sleep-mode-in-android-what-will-happen-to-cpu-once-screen-lcd-light-goes-off)  and [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/95625/what-is-androids-sleep-mode)